# Unable to use certain basic statistical functions in Pandas groupby aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an experiment where 'depth' is measured for varying 'force' and 'scanning speeds'. Five runs are conducted for each set of variables.

I have to compute the maximum depth measured across the five runs as well as the standard deviation of the measurements. To this end, I have constructed a Pandas dataframe as follows:

```
   force  scanspeed  depth
0    0.5         10     3.541  
1    0.5         20     2.531
2    0.5         10     3.020
3      1         10     2.130
4    0.5         20     1.502
5    0.5         10     4.102
6      2         50     2.413
...
(100+ rows)
```

For this dataframe, I want to groupby using the `force` and `scanspeed` columns and generate the maximum and standard deviation for each group (there are multiple rows with the same force and scanspeed). However, in running the following line:

`print(subframe.groupby(['force', 'scanspeed'])['depth'].agg([max, std]))`

the function `std` is not recognized, prompting `NameError: name 'std' is not defined`.

Other functions found not to work include: `mean`, `median`, `corr`, `var`, `count`, `np.std`. I have not tested the full range of functions available but so far it seems like only `max` and `min` work despite all of these functions coming from the same pandas library (aside from np.std of course).

I'd appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Comment: The other functions like `mean` **are** functions. Just type it into the terminal, you will get `<function mean>`. Type `std` and instead you get `NameError`. However `pandas` has convenience methods so that `'std'` allows you to refer to `Series.std()`. The relevant documentation on the matter is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that `np.std` is otherwise accessible in that statements scope, `agg` also allows you to pass names of certain functions as strings:

```
print(subframe.groupby(['force', 'scanspeed'])['depth'].agg([max, 'std']))
```

That line seemed to work for me without importing anything except for pandas.

---

Otherwise, maybe try a call like `np.std([0,1])` right before that statement to make sure it doesn't throw an error as well. Or you could try putting in `import numpy as np` on the line right before.

Comment: Passing `std` as a string throws `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'`. Perhaps I did something wrong with my datatypes, I'll look into it. np.std([0,1]) successfully outputs 0.5.

Comment: Indeed it was the datatype that was an issue. In the pandas dataframe there are other columns that I failed to mention in my original question, of which a column 'lot number' contained strings. Removing this column solves the error, although I'm not sure why as there are no operations being carried out on that column.